# How to use passport in nestjs middleware?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to write authentication middleware. The problem is that my setup throws "Unauthenticated" every time i try to do something.

My middleware:

```
@Middleware()
export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(
    @Inject(constants.logger) private logger: Winston,
  ){}

  resolve(...args: any[]): ExpressMiddleware {
    return passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });
  }
}
```

JwtStrategy class:

```
@Component()
export class JwtStrategy extends Strategy {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    @Inject(constants.config) private readonly config: Config,
  ) {
    super(
      {
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        passReqToCallback: true,
        secretOrKey: config.JWT_SECRET,
      },
      async (req, payload, next) => {
        console.log('hello from verifycb');
        next(null, payload);
      },
    );
    passport.use('jwt', this);
  }

  public async verify(req, payload: TokenData, done) {
    console.log('JwtStrategy::verify(req, payload)', {req, payload});
    const isValid = await this.authService.isUserValid(payload);
    if (!isValid) {
      return done('Unauthorized 22', false);
    }
    done(null, payload);
  }
}
```

Im sure that my middleware called. Am i using it in weird way or what?

Comment: If you find a solution please post the answer!  Not many Nestjs experts on SO yet.

Comment: still no solution, so i diched it

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit late but you need to explicitly `consume` the **Middlewares** in your **Modules**

// active.module.ts

```
@Module({
    ...
})
export class ActiveModule implements NestModule {
    public configure(consumer: MiddlewaresConsumer) {
        consumer.apply(JwtMiddleware).forRoutes(
            {path: '/api/lists/create', method: RequestMethod.POST}
        );
    }
}
```

In this example, `JwtMiddleware` is my middleware, same as your `AuthMiddleware`.

//active.controller.ts

```
@Controller('lists')
export class ActiveController {
    @Post('create')
    async create(@Req() request: Request) {
         // req.user will be available for you
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do you think of this framework? Do you like working with it? It seems horrific when I look at it (`NgModule` is a despicable hack and something that was bolted on between release candidates, anything but well-engineered) and its stated reason for being is not compelling in my view. Just curious I know it's off topic.

Comment: As of the moment, I love working with it. There's nothing wrong with the framework but lack of good tutorials/documentations/implementations which can be added/requested. I'm not sure I get your point but I like it. Until Loopback4 comes out, I stick with NestJS.

Comment: When I first started trying out the framework, I thought of `extra-overhead` but now I like the approach that it's taken. One point to note is I am also an Angular Developer so I'm a fan of the structure ;)

Comment: I've also developed angular applications, one strictly web-based and 1 and ionic mobile app. I very much appreciate your responses. It's not the performance overhead that irks me, it's the complexity of the abstraction, and the server redundancy and maintainability burden inherent in it's very design, of a not unredundant module concept, atop of another, the angular one being complex and, as demonstrated other by other frameworks, unnecessary that contributes to my strong dislike of the idea of generalizing it.

Comment: Not only does it almost literally duplicate the dependency graph, but it at the same time proves to not be amenable to tooling, being inherently opaque and expressed in terms of the most vacuous types (`new<T>(...args) => T)[]` is close to meaningless). This mechanism of organizing code is abhorrent and wastes the capabilities of both JavaScript and TypeScript on top of it. And it definitely was an afterthought as we know from the history of the framework.